# ServiceName not reflected in web services

Tags: java, web-services

I have `serviceName` in my webservice as `MYService`. But in the `wsdl` I am not getting this name. I am still getting `http://localhost:8080/rpc/soap/getResult?wsdl=Info.wsdl`

```
@WebService(portName="portname", serviceName = "MYService", targetNamespace="http://test.com/webservices")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use= SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle= SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface Info {


    ........
}
```

Can some one tell how to rectify it.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the runtime of JAX-WS? Or, better, what's is the app server?

Comment: Apache Axis2 is app server

Comment: Apache Axis 2 is your WS Engine / Runtime .  and also can you post the generated WSDL ?